# Cursor description do not show columns name

Tags: python, pyodbc, web2py, pydal

I have a web2py API application that I recently upgraded from python 2.7.x to python 3.6.3.
The API functions queries a Microsoft SQL database.

When I execute a SQL statement with the option 'as_dict=True', the cursor object use its description attribute to get the columns names from the db table to do some checks, but for some reason, the columns names returned from the database are 'corrupted'.

for example:

DB table:

```
webDataTbl:
_key      |      _value

WEB_NAME        NAME
WEB_VER         '1.2.3'
```

SP:

```
SELECT * FROM  webDataTbl WHERE _key LIKE 'WEB_%'
```

The function in web2py:

```
sql_cmd = ("EXEC getWebData")
result = db.executesql(sql_cmd, as_dict=True)
return {"result": result}
```

executesql method executing the following code (when as_dict=True):

```
columns = adapter.cursor.description
fields = colnames or [f[0] for f in columns]
if len(fields) != len(set(fields))
    raise RuntimeError
```

As [source code](https://web2py.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/pydal/base.html) states,  cursor.description returns a list of 7-item tuples, one tuple for each column returned from the DB, when the first field is the column name (or alias).
But, when I print the tuple, I get this:

```
[(b'c', <class 'str'>, 64, 64, 64, 0, False), (b'c', <class 'str'>, 256, 256, 256, 0, True)]
```

I thought maybe the issue is DB encoding or something, but it didnt help changing the encoding in the sql connection.
I haven't change anything in my code, DB data, SP etc. The only thing I did is to upgrade the version.
notice that the data that fetched is OK. When I don't use the 'as_dict' option and the curser doesn't use the description attribute, everything works fine.

Comment: can you please provide a bit more context to your code? especially for this part: `columns = adapter.cursor.description`

Comment: The column names returned by the driver are `byte` objects, but the DAL `executesql` method converts them to strings (a few lines below the source code you referenced above), so the column names should not be corrupted. What do you mean by corrupted? What is the result of `executesql`?

Comment: Sorry for the late response guys:
@AlexanderRiedel- The curser is an object of the DAL (Database Abstraction Layer)  that represents a database cursor, as you can see [here](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0249/#cursor-objects). The description is an attribute of the curser object that contains information describing the result column (The link attached provides more information).

Comment: @Anthony- not exactly. as you can see in the 'executesql' method, if the 'as_dict' option is true, before converting the columns names from bytes to strings, a check is perfomed, I added the code in my question.

I agree 'corrupted' is not the most accurate term to use. The columns names that returns from the DB (using description) are wrong, as in my question above. please note that the remaining information in the tuple is indeed correct.

Comment: I'm wondering if there's a discrepancy between the underlying libraries. Are you using pyodbc? Is the library version the same on py2 and py3?

Answer (score 1):

I had exactly the same problem trying to do the same, PY27-> PY38 and Web2PY version update 2.14-> 2.21 . Web2py apparently has his own pyodbc. As I connected, I did not realize this, until I saw that I did not have installed in the system (FreeBSD) pyodbc. Once installed everything worked correctly

Jose

EDIT:
What I tried to explain here is that the error happens because Web2py has (at least I think) an outdated pyodbc driver. The solution is  install in the system or virtualenv pyodbc.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).